# How do I test my Web interface Perl program from the command line?

Tags: perl, debugging, shell, command-line

I have access to a Perl module that I call from my Web code passing it query parameter in the usual URI-encoded form (i.e. `myperl.pl?var1=val2&var2-val2&var3=val3`) from AJAX or curl.

How do I test this same module from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a CGI script, then it presumably finds those variables by examining the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable; so, you can try setting that variable from the shell. For example, if you're using Bash, you could write:

```
QUERY_STRING='var1=val2&var2=val2&var3=val3' perl myperl.pl
```

or if you prefer:

```
export QUERY_STRING='var1=val2&var2=val2&var3=val3'
perl myperl.pl
```

(Note that you will likely need to set other environment-variables as well, and perhaps standard input.)

Comment: That's woefully incomplete CGI request. You didn't even specify a REQUEST_METHOD, something one should check before accessing QUERY_STRING.

Comment: It was just for temporary testing of data... Not the planned access method.

Answer (score 3):

Does it use the [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) module? If so, see the [DEBUGGING](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI#DEBUGGING) section of the docs.

```
myperl.pl var1=val2&var2-val2&var3=val3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CGI.pm then I believe the params() function returns parameters from the command line.

```
@vars = $query->param
```

For example

```
myperl.pl "var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3"
```

param() method will returned be variables as a list.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you set the program as executable under the properties then:

```
./program_name.pl param1 param2 param3
```

should work. Unless I misread the question.